# Pandas - Add columns from a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add columns from a list.

newcols = ['D', 'E', 'F']

df1 = (How it is)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | 5 |
| 11 | 14 | 9 |

df2 = (How i want it to be)

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | 5 |  |  |  |
| 11 | 14 | 9 |  |  |  |

Do you guys know how to get this done ??
Best Regards!

Comment: You didn't accept any of the answers. That's not fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the columns [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
df2 = df1.reindex(columns=df.columns.union(newcols))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=newcols)], axis=1)
```

Comment: The headers will not always be "D,E,F", it was just an example.
That's why i need to use the list.

Comment: Just use the list name instead. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

assign directly

```
df[newcols] = ""
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine.
Felling kind of dumd right know hahaha!